# Css and javascript not loading with rewrite condition?

Tags: mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Css and javascript Not Loading in rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120511/css-and-javascript-not-loading-in-rewrite-rule)

After using only rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^profile.php$ profile.php
```

and when i load profile.php the css and javascript are loading

but when make a change in rule and add condition

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/profile.php$
 RewriteRule ^profile.php$ profile.php
```

and then the js and css are not loading

**Coding of profile.php is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-…
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/profile.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <table><tr><td><div class="image"><ul><li>My</li></ul></div>
 </td></tr></table>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: Please don't keep repeating what is essentially the same question. Update the original if you have anything new to add. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the `RewriteCond` says : `apply the following`RewriteRule`only if the url doesn't only contain /profiles`

you should write it like :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /profile.php$
```

(without the exclamation mark)

in add:
If you don't want your mod_rewrite Rules to be apply on scripts and other specific files request, you should write a Rule for them.

E.g.

```
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
```

Comment: +1 but it might be better to use a condition that ignores rewrites for existing files, e.g. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: @Jimmy good point, I'm doing the test (is the content of the requested file avaible ? if not request the content of a page not found).
I never worked with this instruction, turns out it's a good alternative.